# Any practical difference between Clang versions 2.8 and 3.1 for a C developer?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, clang

I will be working exclusively in C. Ubunutu 10.10 will retrieve version 2.8 of Clang from it's repositories and fully install it. I have compiled Clang v 3.1 from source and have added it to the path (after uninstalling Clang 2.8), but do not have access to it's man pages this way, and have an occasional nagging feeling about not having fully "installed it", though it appears to be fully functional on some testing.

Is there any practical difference between versions 2.8 and 3.1 from a C developer's (student actually)  point of view? I am working exclusively in C and will not tap into it's C++ or objective C capabilities. I believe most of the development in Clang recently has been in extending it's C++ abilities.

Comment: Why don't you read the release notes and tell us what you found?

Comment: I would believe that the optimizations and the warnings did improve (even for C). Likewise, for the recent evolutions of GCC.

Answer (score 2):

The noticeable difference I found is that for 2.8 VLA function parameters make the compiler dump core. In 2.9 (and thus in 3.1 I suppose) this bug seems to be fixed.

Also this newer version of clang already implements part of C11, in particular `_Generic`.

Comment: Note: some C11 features that already work in gcc/icc dump core in clang (3.1), most prominently the designated initialisation of anonymous structs and unions

Comment: @hroptatyr: Many extensions are missing however. Clang is much better now at C++ than it is at C.